# human feet detection through Android Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, detection, face-detection

We can detect face feature in Android. But I want to detect hand and leg too.

How can we detect these? Is there any other classes or logic using which we can detect these.

Comment: Please add some other Tag like Camera ..

Answer (score 1):

There is no Android class that allows you to detect human feet or hands as there is with face detection. You would have to write your own detection scheme.